# Gulp minify css doesn't work in IE9

Tags: css, gulp, internet-explorer-9, minify

I have a problem with my gulp minify css.

It works perfectly on IE10, 11, edge, chrome, etc.

But it's not working on IE9, all my css is break...

Somebody has an explanation or solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some incompatible CSS properties with IE?

Comment: No, for imcompatible css properties with IE, I have my own style sheet.

Comment: I just discover that I could be the file size, which is 500kb and IE9 apaprently doesn't support css file up to 288kb

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you reached the filesize limit, you could try to [use gulp-bless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bless) to split your css file.